# Adding preview of Non-featured image in Shopify / Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

On Shopify, product cards display 'featured media' (i.e. the first image of all of its images) using the following liquid code (this is using the default Shopify theme).

```
  {% capture img_id %}ProductCardImage-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture wrapper_id %}ProductCardImageWrapper-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
  {%- assign preview_image = product.featured_media.preview_image -%}
  {%- assign img_url = preview_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}

  {% unless preview_image == blank %}
    {% include 'image-style', image: preview_image, height: max_height, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id: img_id %}
  {% endunless %}
```

I want to display another image (e.g. the second one) when hovering over the product, meaning I need to be able to call a different image and not just the featured image.

How would I change the code from product.featured_media to instead call a different image?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `product.media` attribute to access all the media items assigned to products.

This is an array so you can use loops e.g.

```
{% for media in product.media %}
  {{ media | img_tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Consequently, you can access the second media using `product.media[1]`.

Useful links:

- [Media filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/media-filters)
- [Adding media to themes](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-theme-support-for-rich-media-3d-and-video)

Comment: Great thanks, didn't realise how simple it was. Much appreciated.